# Tensorflow Conv2D SAME padding when Stride is larger than Kernel Size

Tags: tensorflow, convolution, cross-correlation

I'm running into a weird issue trying to compare my implementation of a convolution operator with tensorflow's dealing with the SAME padding.

According to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Convolution) post the SAME padding is calculated as follows:

```
//n_i = input size for ith dimension
//k_i = filter size in ith dimension
//s_i = stride in ith dimension
//p_i = total padding in the ith dimension

if((n_i % s_i) == 0)
    p_i = max(k_i - s_i, 0)
else
    p_i = max(k_i - (n_i % s_i), 0)
```

I was running some random testing and narrowed down a mismatch between my implementation and tensorflow's with the following tf(1.4.0) program:

```
#input size: (3x1) values: [1.0, 1.1, 1.2]
#filter size: (1x1) values: [1.0]
#stride: (3x1)
#output size: (1x1)
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

i = tf.constant((np.ones(3) + np.arange(3) * 0.1).reshape(1,3,1,1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input')
f = tf.constant(np.ones(1).reshape(1,1,1,1), dtype=tf.float32, name='filter')

conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input=i, filter=f, strides=(1,3,1,1), padding='SAME')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    out = sess.run(conv)
    print out
```

Since the filter is 1x1, and it's value is 1.0, it will be easy to see which input element the is used to calculate the output value:

```
Expected output is [[[[ 1.0]]]]
TF output is [[[[ 1.1]]]]
```

Changing the padding to 'VALID' gives the expected result of 1.0:

```
Expected output is [[[[ 1.0]]]]
TF output is [[[[ 1.1]]]]
```

Alternatively if you change the stride to be (2x1) we get expected result for output[0]:

```
// output size is now: (2x1)
Expected output is [[[[ 1.0 ]] [[ 1.2]]]]
TF output is [[[[ 1.0 ]] [[ 1.2]]]]
```

Any guess as to what's going on? My only thought is that the actual TF implementation is not protecting against the padding calculation from going negative and it's calling tf.pad (or something equivalent) with a negative padding, and as a result actually removing the first element of the input, making the new (padded) input[0] = 1.1.

Comment: I don't the answer to this specific problem (I find the TensorFlow padding deeply confusing even though I wrote some of the code to handle it!) but there is a reference Conv2D implementation here that may help: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/quantized_conv_ops.cc#L51